# raise delayed exception in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am wondering if there is a standard mechanism in python for this use case:

```
try:
    do_a()
    if something_happens():
        raise DelayedException # is really only raised after do_b()
    do_b()
except DelayedException as de:
    # handle de after the entire try/except block completed
```

I could obviously just store the exception information in a variable to handle later, but I'm wondering if there is such a mechanism built into python (3.x if that makes a difference).

EDIT:
To clarify, in my use case, the exception handling requires the outcome of do_b().

Comment: What would you want to happen if `do_b()` raised its own exception?

Comment: Doesn't wrapping `do_something()` in a try-finally block (with `do_b()` in the finally block) do this?

Comment: Nope, not a thing. This doesn't look like a use case for exceptions; just record the error and check it later.

Comment: @dhke: That runs `do_b` after the `except` instead of before.

Comment: @user2357112 You are thinking of a try-except-finally, are you? To get the finally before the exception handler, you need an inner try-finally block.

Comment: Unless you meant to have a second `try` inside the first `try`, and attach the `finally` to the new `try`, I suppose. It'd be a pretty confusing code structure.

Comment: Looks like that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, but it's ugly:

```
try:
    do_a()
    try:
        if do_something():
            raise DelayedException()
    finally:
        do_b()
except DelayedException:
    pass
```

Comment: It is a bit ugly indeed! It took me a couple reads to understand how this works, so I guess it's not a good sign, and probably using variables would make the intent clearer.